# Zebra stripe command output

Tags: code-golf

I have a script:

```
$ cat ~/zebra.pl
#!/bin/perl
use Term::ANSIColor;

$Term::ANSIColor::EACHLINE = "\n";

my $zebra = 1; # Are zebras black with white stripes, or white with black stripes?!

my $black = color('white on_black');
my $blue = color('white on_blue');

while (<>){
    chomp($_);

    $zebra = $zebra == 1 ? 0 : 1;

    ($zebra == 1 && print $blue) || print $black;

    print $_;

    ($zebra == 1 && print $black) || print $blue;

    print "\n";
}

print color('reset');
```

Usage:

```
some-command | zebra
```

The output consists of alternating lines that have black and blue backgrounds, respectively. The script seems needlessly long and complex. I'm wondering how much shorter it could be.

Comment: Actually Perl also can do it in 31 characters: `some-command | perl -pe '$_="\e[4".$.%2*4 .";37m$_\e[m"'`. So I can't really see where the actual challenge is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Sed: 45 characters

```
1~2s/^/\e[40;37m/;2~2s/^/\e[44;37m/;s/$/\e[m/
```

Usage:

```
some-command | sed $'1~2s/^/\e[40;37m/;2~2s/^/\e[44;37m/;s/$/\e[m/'
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#: <strike>105</strike> 84

Easy.  You just need some sort of marker, and your infinite loop.  From there, things are rather easy.

(Assumes `using System;`, this is just a method body.)

```
bool b=false;while(true){Console.WriteLine((b?"Blue":"Black")+" background!");b=!b;}
```

Comment: You can tweak one more byte with `b=1==0;` ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Awk: <strike>56</strike> 52 characters

```
{x="\x1b[37;4";y=NR%2;print x (y?0:4)"m"$0x 4*y"m"}
```

```
{x="\x1b[37;4%dm";printf x"%s"x"\n",NR%2?0:4,$0,NR%2*4}
```